# changing an double array field to a single array in hive or pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a field `interest_product_id` which looks something like below -

```
a.select('cust_id', 'interest_product_id').show(1,False)
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
|cust_id        |interest_product_id                           |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
|4308c3w994     |[[73ndy0-885bns-ysrd, isgbf-6322-734f4-92j72]]|
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The schema is as below -

```
root
 |-- cust_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- interest_product_id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

As the field `interest_product_id` is of array type and also the element is array(string) the field shows [[**]]. How can I convert it to a array(string)??

Expected outcome -

```
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
|cust_id        |interest_product_id                           |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
|4308c3w994     |[73ndy0-885bns-ysrd, isgbf-6322-734f4-92j72]  |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Please suggest the best way. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`flatten`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.flatten.html?highlight=flatten), creates a flat array from nested arrays.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("4308c3w994", [["73ndy0-885bns-ysrd", "isgbf-6322-734f4-92j72"]], )], ("cust_id", "interest_product_id", ))

df.withColumn("interest_product_id", F.flatten(F.col("interest_product_id"))).show(truncate=False)
```

### Output

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|cust_id   |interest_product_id                         |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|4308c3w994|[73ndy0-885bns-ysrd, isgbf-6322-734f4-92j72]|
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```